# What is the difference between these two blocks of JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Here's the code:

```
<form action="">
        <input type="text" id="new_task" placeholder="Write New Task" required>
        <input type="button" value="Add Task" id="add_task">
    </form>
    <div id="task_list"> 
    </div>
```

Code 1:

```
document.getElementById("add_task").addEventListener("click",function(){
    let new_task = document.getElementById("new_task").value;
    document.getElementById("task_list").append(document.createElement("p").textContent=new_task);
});
```

Code 2:

```
document.getElementById("add_task").addEventListener("click",function(){
    let new_task = document.getElementById("new_task").value;
    let task_div = document.getElementById("task_list");
    let task_p = document.createElement("p");
    task_p.textContent = new_task;
    task_div.append(task_p);
});
```

What is the difference between the two blocks of code?
I am trying to make a todo list website.
The first piece of code was appending the value from input inside the div but not creating p tag.
The second piece of code worked perfectly.
I want to know the difference.

Comment: `=` operator returns the value of the assignment

Answer (score 1):

The significant difference is this section of code block 1:

```js
.append(document.createElement("p").textContent=new_task)
```

This does in fact create a `<p>` tag ***but*** it is not appended to the document yet. When you set the text content on this new `<p>` tag, that expression evaluates to the string `new_task`, so it's the same as saying

```js
.append(new_task)
```

which is definitely not what you want.

The full expanded version of what code block 1 is essentially doing is:

```js
document.getElementById("add_task").addEventListener("click",function(){
    let new_task = document.getElementById("new_task").value;
    let task_div = document.getElementById("task_list");
    let task_p = document.createElement("p");
    task_p.textContent = new_task;
    task_div.append(new_task);
    // different from:
    // task_div.append(task_p)
});
```